# How to stop the person using my stole phone what app?

Tags: 2.3.3-gingerbread

Since my phone been stolen..I already blocked my phone..so the new SIM card resend back..when I install at new phone.i find out my what app still been use...so what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Sign in with your number in another phone then the other person won't use your account anymore. WhatsApp can only be used in one phone at a time